# why angularjs is not supported in old eclipse versions

Tags: angularjs

I am new to anugularjs. I am having eclipse Indigo service. I am able to execute some of the angularjs example using notepad++ but routing examples are not working so I tried to use eclipse, but angularjs simple examples are also not working eclipse version: indigo service release 2.Do I need to install any plugins for it to support.

Comment: not sure about eclipse..but you can try brackets from adobe     http://brackets.io/

Comment: Thanks Anirudh...brackets is helpful but not able to understand what is the problem with eclipse. When i import angular js javascript file , I am getting many errors.